# How do I include a self-reference to a server control in an external method call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have an Asp.Net TextBox control whose enabled property I need to evaluate using a separate (from the code-behind of the containing page) class. The way I want to do this is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTB" runat="server" Enabled="<% ToggleControl(this, "someBusinessValue") %>" ... />
```

The reason I need to pass a reference to the calling control is to see if there are other properties I may need to consider before disabling it. The 'this' keyword, however, refers to the page as a whole. And since my TextBox can be within a FormView, or GridView, I can't easily just get the control by examining 'page.myTB'. I don't want to have to start ploughing through GridViews on the receiving class file just to retrieve a reference to the TextBox.

Does anyone know how to refer to the control inline in this way?

**EDIT 1:** This will need to be done to several different types of server control, such as ListBox, CheckBox, RadioButtonList, etc.

**EDIT 2:** The best I've come up with so far is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTB" runat="server" Enabled="<% ToggleControl(myGridView.FindControl("myTB") as WebControl, "someBusinessValue") %>"
```

which isn't too elegant, but it does give me that auto-reference that I need.

Comment: Thats an interesting dilemma actually. Usually when i need my control to have some logic i would subclass it to my own special TextBox that has contains the logic inside itself. After all, thats whats OO is all about!

Comment: Normally we would do that but the behaviour we want is applicable to all input controls, so we would like to avoid having to subclass each input control that exists (and require new ones to do this also).

We were also considering using webcontroladapters perhaps but its a little bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue of UI/Data/Code separation.

I think you need to write a wrapper for your data source so that all data is available to it before it binds. This will avoid having to find nested controls and so forth...

===========================================================

You never want to pass controls to any other object. The reason is that if you have to change the application's UI, you have to rebuild everything that has reference to that UI element.

Here is a simpler approach to display that data:

DataSource(table)->ORM/Custom Data Object or Collection->Instance Of Object/Collection On Page->UI.

Your UI idealy needs to bind to that object instance which hypothetically will be saved (and wrapped in a public or protected property) to any of the state objects provided by asp.net on the page (Session/AppState/ViewState).

Updates in the UI can be propagated via a transaction (using System.Transaction.TransactionScope) to the object stored in the state as well as the data source, which would ensure that your data source is the same as your disconnected data , while providing graceful degradation in case of failure.

When accessing the instance of the object/collection by your runtime/other pages a public property or variable will facilitate this objective.

This concept removes the need to pass controls. You are only passing data objects back and forth between objects/ui elements that consume them or take actions on their behalf.

Updates that occur inside two or more runtime components can be advertised to others via the Observer pattern or simple delegates...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question...

```
Enabled='<%# ToggleControl(FindControl("txtSomething") as WebControl,new SomeAssessor().EnabledWhenIdXyz) %>'
```

You could use this helper in your code behind

```
public bool ToggleControl(WebControl control, Func<WebControl, bool> assessControl)
{
    return assessControl(control);
}
```

And this is the separate class you mentioned

```
public class SomeAssessor
{
    public bool EnabledWhenIdXyz(WebControl control)
    {
        return control.ID == "txtSomething2";
    }
}
```

---

Here is a suggested idea to do instead:
You might have a `IEnumerable<SomeModel>` returned from your data source for your gridview.
SomeViewModel object is a transform of the original data into an exact 'shape' required for your control.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Make a mapper which converts the model to the view, and here the Enabled evaluation can happen.

```
public interface IMapper<TModel, TViewModel>
{
    TViewModel MapModelToView(TModel source);
}

public class SomeMapper : IMapper<IEnumerable<SomeModel>, IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>>
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> MapModelToView(IEnumerable<SomeModel> source)
    {
        return source.Select(x => new SomeViewModel
                                      {
                                          Id = x.Id,
                                          Name = x.Name,
                                          Enabled = true //call to your method and resolve
                                      });
    }
}
```

Then query your data as `IEnumerable<SomeModel>`, map it, and use `IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>` as the GridView's datasource.

You can then write the following evaluation in your textbox:

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can derive any control, add a new property like "AuthExpression", and use a data-binding expression which you can eval with DataBinder.Eval method.

Or you can create an ASP.NET AJAX extender control which does this job for any control you like: any control extended by the extender evals a data-binding expression which determines that the control should be enabled or disabled.

I hope this is answering your question!